# Combining seperate Schema.org Organization sections in Microdata

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata

I can't seem to figure out the correct way to combine my logo section, address section and social media into one schema organization section.

The following code is attempting to use the `itemref` attribute to combine the three separate areas.

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization" itemref="schemabiz schemabiz2" >
    <a itemprop="url" href="www.address.com">
        <div itemprop=" legalName"><strong>Business Name</strong></div>
    </a>
    <a itemprop="url" href="http://www.website.com">Home</a>
    <img itemprop="logo" src="logo.png" />
</div>

<!-- Some content -->

<div id="schemabiz">
    <div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
        <span itemprop="streetAddress">Address</span>
        <span itemprop="addressLocality">City</span>
        <span itemprop="addressRegion">CO</span>
        <span itemprop="postalCode">80525</span>
        <span itemprop="addressCountry">United States</span>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Some content -->

<div id="schemabiz2" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
  <a itemprop="sameAs" href="http://www.facebook.com/your-company">FB</a>
  <a itemprop="sameAs" href="http://www.twitter.com/YourCompany">Twitter</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### For *schemabiz*

It works like that.

But you could also omit the outer `div` and add the `id` to the `PostalAddress` item.

So instead of

```html
<div id="schemabiz">
    <div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
    </div>
</div>
```

you could use

```html
<div id="schemabiz" itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
</div>
```

#### For *schemabiz2*

Don’t use `itemscope`+`itemtype` for the referenced element.

So instead of

```html
<div id="schemabiz2" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
</div>
```

you should use

```html
<div id="schemabiz2">
</div>
```

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you for clarifying that the contents of the target only need to be tagged, but not defined/associated with a specific type on their own. Only the main section invoking the itemref needs a type.